# Perform Union using joins not union ALL

Tags: sql, join, cloud, union, informatica

We are having a requirement where in we are trying to perform union operation for the tables of 2 different databases using informatica cloud, we dont have union transformation in it. So trying to explore if this can be performed using a left/full outer join ?

```
select * from t join p on t.id = p.id
union
select * from t join p on t.id = p.id2
```

Note: Not Union ALL only Union

Comment: here T is from teradata and p is from oracle, and we are trying to join t and p twice. so the query posted is correct in terms of our data extraction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between `union` and `union all` is simply the removal of distinct values.  The answer to your question is that you can emulate `union` using a bunch of `coalesce()` statements, `select distinct`, and `full join`.

However, why not just do:

```
select *
from t join
     p
     on t.id in (p.id, p.id2);
```

Depending on the data, you might need `select distinct`:

```
select distinct *
from t join
     p
     on t.id in (p.id, p.id2);
```